# R - Counting total occurrences of word from list that appears in data frame, and grouped

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID   Word
1    Tree
1    House
1    Tree
2    Snail
2    Tree
3    Car
```

And I have a list of keywords I want to check for:

```
(House, Tree, Bird)
```

I want to know how many times for each ID, any word in my list of keywords appears.

I.e. the word House, Tree or Bird appears 3 times in ID(1), and House, Tree or Bird appears only once in ID(2), and there are no occurrences in ID(3)

```
ID   Count
1     3
2     1
3     0
```

I am not sure how to tackle this. I know how to count the number of times a word appears within each ID, but not how many times the words from another list appear.

Thank you for any suggestions/guidance etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical index and get the `sum` grouped by 'ID'.  Not sure whether the 'v1' is `vector` or `list` (if it is `list`, then `unlist(v1)` and use it with the same code)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(Count = sum(Word %in% v1))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID Count
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     3
#2     2     1
#3     3     0
```

---

Or `filter` and then do a `count`

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(Word %in% v1) %>%
   count(ID, .drop = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("House", "Tree", "Bird")
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Word = c("Tree", 
"House", "Tree", "Snail", "Tree", "Car")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Wow, that was so quick. Works perfectly. Thank you ever so much! I have spent hours on this! I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I am able to :)

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `table` to count number of `Word` that has `vec` in it for each `ID`.

```
table(df$ID, df$Word %in% vec)

#    FALSE TRUE
#  1     0    3
#  2     1    1
#  3     1    0
```

Here rownames (1, 2, 3) are the ID's `FALSE` is the count of number of `Word` that are not present in `vec` for each `ID` whereas `TRUE` is the count of number of `Word` that are present for each `ID`.

To get the exact expected output we can convert the table to dataframe and take only the `TRUE`column as count.

```
data <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$ID, df$Word %in% vec))
data.frame(ID = rownames(data), count = data$`TRUE`)

#  ID count
#1  1     3
#2  2     1
#3  3     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative option in base R. Really useful :)